# Android. Registration using get request

Tags: android

I'm trying to realize a user registration on android using get request. It takes an email and password. So it doesn't work and nothing is being sent to the server. Thanks to those who will try to help me.

RegWindow.java

```
package com.example.sadaka;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class RegWindow extends Activity {
    EditText name;
    EditText lastname;
    EditText address;
    EditText password;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.reg_window);

        Button r_confirm,r_login,r_skip;
        name=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);
        lastname=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.lastname);
        address=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.address);
        password=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.r_password);
        r_confirm=(Button)findViewById(R.id.r_confirm);
        r_login=(Button)findViewById(R.id.r_login);
        r_skip=(Button)findViewById(R.id.r_skip);

        r_confirm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                try{
                    String loginValue    = URLEncoder.encode(name.getText().toString(), "UTF-8");
                    String fnameValue  = URLEncoder.encode(lastname.getText().toString(), "UTF-8");
                    String emailValue   = URLEncoder.encode(address.getText().toString(), "UTF-8");
                    String passValue    = URLEncoder.encode(password.getText().toString(), "UTF-8");
                    HttpClient Client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    String URL="http://sadakafund.com/api/add_user.php?name="+loginValue+"&surname="+fnameValue+"&email="+emailValue+"&password="+passValue;
                   try{
                    String SetServerString = "";
                    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(URL);
                    ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
                    SetServerString = Client.execute(httpget, responseHandler);

                    }catch(Exception ex){
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                        name.setText("error!!! ");
                    }
                }
                catch(UnsupportedEncodingException ex){
                    name.setText("error");
                }
                }

        });
        r_login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent=new Intent("com.example.sadaka.Splash");
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        r_skip.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent=new Intent("com.example.sadaka.MAINACTIVITY");
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.reg_window, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

reg_window.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/splash" >

    <EditText 
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Имя"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/lastname"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Фамилия"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/address"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="e-mail"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/r_password"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/r_confirm"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="register"/>

    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/r_login"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="login"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/r_skip"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="skip"/>"

</LinearLayout>
```

LogCat

```
    06-04 10:11:52.238: W/EGL_genymotion(3436): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
06-04 10:11:58.190: W/EGL_genymotion(3436): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
06-04 10:12:07.390: W/EGL_genymotion(3436): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
06-04 10:12:11.470: W/System.err(3436): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
06-04 10:12:11.470: W/System.err(3436):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1133)
06-04 10:12:11.470: W/System.err(3436):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
06-04 10:12:11.470: W/System.err(3436):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
06-04 10:12:11.470: W/System.err(3436):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
06-04 10:12:11.470: W/System.err(3436):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
06-04 10:12:11.470: W/System.err(3436):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
06-04 10:12:11.470: W/System.err(3436):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
06-04 10:12:11.470: W/System.err(3436):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
06-04 10:12:11.470: W/System.err(3436):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
06-04 10:12:11.470: W/System.err(3436):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:653)
06-04 10:12:11.470: W/System.err(3436):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:627)
06-04 10:12:11.470: W/System.err(3436):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:616)
06-04 10:12:11.470: W/System.err(3436):     at com.example.sadaka.RegWindow$1.onClick(RegWindow.java:60)
06-04 10:12:11.470: W/System.err(3436):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
06-04 10:12:11.470: W/System.err(3436):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
06-04 10:12:11.474: W/System.err(3436):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
06-04 10:12:11.474: W/System.err(3436):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-04 10:12:11.474: W/System.err(3436):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-04 10:12:11.474: W/System.err(3436):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
06-04 10:12:11.474: W/System.err(3436):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-04 10:12:11.474: W/System.err(3436):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
06-04 10:12:11.474: W/System.err(3436):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
06-04 10:12:11.474: W/System.err(3436):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
06-04 10:12:11.474: W/System.err(3436):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-04 10:14:59.498: D/dalvikvm(3513): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 147K, 9% free 2715K/2972K, paused 2ms, total 2ms
06-04 10:14:59.498: I/dalvikvm-heap(3513): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.610MB for 901180-byte allocation
06-04 10:14:59.506: D/dalvikvm(3513): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 7% free 3593K/3856K, paused 7ms, total 7ms
06-04 10:14:59.518: D/dalvikvm(3513): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 7% free 3593K/3856K, paused 2ms, total 2ms
06-04 10:14:59.522: I/dalvikvm-heap(3513): Grow heap (frag case) to 7.045MB for 3604684-byte allocation
06-04 10:14:59.526: D/dalvikvm(3513): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 4% free 7113K/7380K, paused 4ms, total 4ms
06-04 10:14:59.622: D/libEGL(3513): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_genymotion.so
06-04 10:14:59.622: D/(3513): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb7f81060, tid 3513
06-04 10:14:59.630: D/libEGL(3513): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_genymotion.so
06-04 10:14:59.630: D/libEGL(3513): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_genymotion.so
06-04 10:14:59.674: W/EGL_genymotion(3513): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
06-04 10:14:59.674: E/OpenGLRenderer(3513): Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from GradienCache
06-04 10:14:59.686: E/OpenGLRenderer(3513): Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from Caches::initConstraints()
06-04 10:14:59.686: D/OpenGLRenderer(3513): Enabling debug mode 0
06-04 10:15:02.086: W/EGL_genymotion(3513): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
06-04 10:15:12.858: W/EGL_genymotion(3513): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
06-04 10:15:17.398: W/EGL_genymotion(3513): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
06-04 10:15:21.026: W/EGL_genymotion(3513): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
06-04 10:15:29.690: W/EGL_genymotion(3513): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
06-04 10:15:33.630: W/System.err(3513): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
06-04 10:15:33.638: W/System.err(3513):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1133)
06-04 10:15:33.638: W/System.err(3513):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
06-04 10:15:33.638: W/System.err(3513):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
06-04 10:15:33.638: W/System.err(3513):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
06-04 10:15:33.638: W/System.err(3513):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
06-04 10:15:33.638: W/System.err(3513):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
06-04 10:15:33.638: W/System.err(3513):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
06-04 10:15:33.638: W/System.err(3513):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
06-04 10:15:33.638: W/System.err(3513):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
06-04 10:15:33.638: W/System.err(3513):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:653)
06-04 10:15:33.638: W/System.err(3513):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:627)
06-04 10:15:33.638: W/System.err(3513):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:616)
06-04 10:15:33.642: W/System.err(3513):     at com.example.sadaka.RegWindow$1.onClick(RegWindow.java:60)
06-04 10:15:33.642: W/System.err(3513):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
06-04 10:15:33.642: W/System.err(3513):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
06-04 10:15:33.642: W/System.err(3513):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
06-04 10:15:33.642: W/System.err(3513):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-04 10:15:33.642: W/System.err(3513):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-04 10:15:33.642: W/System.err(3513):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
06-04 10:15:33.642: W/System.err(3513):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-04 10:15:33.646: W/System.err(3513):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
06-04 10:15:33.646: W/System.err(3513):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
06-04 10:15:33.646: W/System.err(3513):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
06-04 10:15:33.646: W/System.err(3513):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Put your code of getting data from URL in Asynctask. It will execute without error.

Comment: I think you should see the example. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: Just create one Asynctask class and add your code in doInBackground() method.To execute class use `new YourClassName().execute();`

Comment: I put that class into different places but the code in method doesn't see it

Comment: See this [example](http://www.compiletimeerror.com/2013/01/why-and-how-to-use-asynctask.html#.U47HlnZ_08g) of AsyncTask. You can find your solution.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are trying to do networking in the main thread thus catching the `NetworkOnMainThreadException`. When doing networking in android you need to do it in a separate Thread.

**solution:**

Asynctask is the best solution for it. you can [click here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for more info about the Asynctask.
  Put all your networking stuff in the `doInBackground()` method of the AsyncTask because it is run on a separate thread.

Answer (score 0):

You can move onClick code to Custom Async Class. Check the sample below

```
   class CustomAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

        protected doBackground(String... URL){
                        HttpClient Client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                       try{
                        String SetServerString = "";
                        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(URL[0]);
                        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
                        SetServerString = Client.execute(httpget, responseHandler);

         }catch(Exception e){}
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
        }
```

Invoke using new CustomAsync().execute("http://sadakafund.com/api/add_user.php?name="+loginValue+"&surname="+fnameValue+"&email="+emailValue+"&password="+passValue");

Comment: why loginValue is different?

Comment: Ohh. Yeah.. @user3579259. Ur correct. I updated code. Check again!!

Comment: I had to put CustomAsync ca=new CustomAsync();
     ca.execute(); into r_confirm after Strings declaration. but I couldnt put URL into ca.execute();

Comment: when im trying to do CustomAsync ca=new CustomAsync();
     ca.doBackground(URL); it throws an exception

Comment: Just look at this example http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/os/asynctask/android-asynctask-example/.  You seems to be confusing. Just understand above examples and implement. Thanks